# Cannot download unknown extensions

Tags: android, download

I cannot download (from web & from e-mail) unkwown extentions such as (*.ini, *.zip, *.ddd)
unless there exists an app that can understand the extention.

For example, I couldn't download *.ini file from the browser (or email) until I downloaded 'Astro' app.

1. How can you by pass so that they are downloadable?
2. How can you register your app to understan certain extention so that it can be downloadable?

Comment: This isn't a programming question. And the answer to this depends on what browser you're using.

Comment: This is still a programming question because I am asking how my app to register the extention so that it could be downloadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="file" />
            <data
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.ini" />
            <data
                android:host="*" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Above code allowed me to download *.ini files.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> How can you by pass so that they are downloadable?

You don't.

> How can you register your app to understan certain extention so that it can be downloadable?

Ideally, you don't. You do it by MIME type. File extensions are very fragile. However, either can be achieved via the use of the `<data>` element in your activity's `<intent-filter>`. You will also want the `BROWSEABLE` category and probably the `VIEW` action.

For example, here is how you would arrange to be an option for viewing PDF files:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
</intent-filter>
```