# Intent Filter for Viewing Web Pages

Tags: java, android, webview

On [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) page of Android Development, -at step 6- they say :

> Instead of adding an intent filter to
>   view web pages, you can override the
>   WebViewClient class and enable this
>   Activity to handle its own URL
>   requests.

But I would like to learn how to do it with intent-filters as well.

I have a **WebView** widget and a **Button** widget on my default Activity and when user clicks on the Button, the WebView loads a page - pretty simple. But as it is mentioned in [Step-6](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html), I need to enable my **Activity** to do so.

Can somebody show me intent-filter which does the same things here as `WebViewClient` - overriding `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I would like to learn how to do it with intent-filters as well.

This is effectively the same thing as a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340379/cannot-download-unknown-extensions), asked minutes before yours, though they might not seem so on the surface.

You can advertise, via a properly-constructed `<data>` element in your `<intent-filter>`, that you can `VIEW` documents that are `text/html`. However, the user will be prompted for *every link* to a Web page they click on *anywhere on their phone* (plus redirects).